# Facebook 'Like' Popup Covering AdSense Banner

Tags: facebook, adsense

Afternoon. I am currently working a drink search site and started work on adding social media to the search results and detail pages. After a user enters in their search criteria and the results are returned, I have added FB (Facebook) and TW (Twitter) buttons for each result, this way the user can Like or Tweet directly from the results page. However I ran into an issue, the FB and TW links are to the right of every result and I have a skyscraper ad about 10px to the right of the results, so when a user clicks on FB Like, the popup appears behind the ad. Obviously this won't work as it is against Google's TOS to render popups over their Ads, so it got me thinking, there are two ways I can handle this:

1. Remove the social media links from the results page and render them only on the detail page. I feel the page load impact of rendering social media links, for every result, is limited, as my pagination is currently set to 15 results per page and the JS is asynchronous.
2. Revisit the UI to move the social icons elsewhere so when a user clicks FB Like, the popup isn't obscuring any Ads.

Wanted to pose this question to the SO community to see if anyone else has come across this issue before and what they ended up doing to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to keep the Twitter and Facebook links on the results pages along with detail pages, in order to avoid the overlap issue I just tweaked the UI so the buttons are more too the left and won't cover up the right ad.